# How can we implement long running task in background in iOS?

Tags: ios

Recently I got requirement from my client that we need to process some execution in background. This execution may be for 10 min or 20 min long.

Is there any way to achieve this? I know iOS has listed few apps type & only those can be run in background. But I checked & my app is not fitting in that listed all apps type. So now I am doubtful in this.

Any one has solution?

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: Take a look at this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) look for this part "Executing Finite-Length Tasks", i think that solves you problem. Because you have a background task that is not Infinite and you can ask for more time to complete the task

Comment: @user3347272 Check my ans.

Comment: José's link is the best available solution. There is no complete solution to your requirement. You cannot run an iOS app for arbitrarily long periods of time in the background. It is explicitly forbidden by App Store, even if you came up with some tricky workaround. Running image processing for 10-20 minutes is far too much battery consumption for an iPhone anyway. This is not a good fit for performing on device.

Answer (score 0):

//  Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^(void) {
      // Perform long running process

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // Update the UI

});
});
 // Continue doing other stuff
```

Comment: Will it helps to run long running task for infinite time?

Comment: This code is related to running a background queue while an app is in the foreground. I believe the question here is asking how to run processes when the app is itself in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Use **Background fetch** is available in Capabilities.

Background fetch mode is execute every 10 min.

Refer to the sample Code here : https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/background-fetch-ios/

Forgot this method **beginBackgroundUploadTask** from above tutorial.

Comment: Here my background task is not downloading some content from internet. My background task runs locally and do some image processing in background. So here this background fetch won't work.

Comment: Background fetch only gives you a few seconds to download some data. It's not for running arbitrarily long processes. Just because you ask for 10 minutes doesn't mean you'll get it. The system can and does rate limit you.